# How to show there is no magic cube of order 2?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, magic-square

I am reading Richard A. Brualdi's Introductory Combinatorics (Ch1.2).

> Three-dimensional analogs of magic squares have been considered. A magic cube of order n is an n-by-n-by-n cubical array constructed out of the integers 1,2, ... , n3 in such a way that the sum s of the integers in the n cells of each of the following straight lines is the same: 
>   (1) lines parallel to an edge of the cube; 
>   (2) the two diagonals of each plane cross section; 
>   (3) the four space diagonals. 
>   The number s is called the magic sum of the magic cube and has the value (n4 +n)/2. We leave it as an easy exercise to show that there is no magic cube of order 2

I am not sure how to begin and would appreciate a tip on how to approach this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each layer of a magic cube must be a magic square.  There is no magic square of order $2$, even with the numbers not in series.  Write the square as 
$$ \begin {array}{c c}a&b\\c&d \end {array}$$
and note that $a+b=a+d, b=d$, similarly for other pairs, and all the numbers must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The magic sum will be $\frac{2^4 + 2}{2} = 9$, which means that each pair needs to contain exactly one odd number.

Comment: How can we show there is no magic cube using the fact that each pair in the sums will contain exactly one odd number? For example, if I were to take one of the faces I would still have

(a+b=9)
(c+d=9)
(a+d=9)
(c+b=9)

I'm stuck because I don't know the parity of any single digit.

Comment: @kaleidoscope Take any 3 of the cells of the magic cube and say their numbers are $a,b,c$. There's no way to have each pair $(a,b),(a,c),(b,c)$ have exactly one odd value.